# Modals Laravel 5.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have this code:

```html
<!-- line modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="squarespaceModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h3 class="modal-title" id="lineModalLabel">Prašymas Dėl Pakvietimo</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      
            <!-- content goes here -->

  @if($errors->any())
     @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
      <li class="alert alert-danger">{{$error}}</li>
    </ul>
     @endforeach
  @endif


  {!! Form::open(['url' => 'sukurti', 'id' => 'frm']) !!}

  @include('components.forma')

  {!! Form::close() !!}


  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Want I want to do here is to show errors without closing the modal. Because if now I leave blank spaces and press submit, the modal shuts down and if I'm press one more time on button to show modal than I can see the error. How to make make that when spaces blank I press enter the modal wont close and just stay but with errors ?

Comment: where is the modal code ?

Comment: The form ? or the modal ? Because this is what gives me modal

Answer (score 0):

To Work like that you have to make few adjustment in your code .

Jquery will handle your submit action . Make a submit event like ;

```
$('#frm').submit(function(e){
 //stop default submit 
 e.preventDefault();
 //make checks here now check for space . 
 var field =  trim($('fieldname').val());
 //of course you can apply some jquery validation library here too . 
 if(field.length > 0){
    //submit form but you need to perform ajax for saving data here
    //on ajax success close you modal
    //here if you have some server side validation error then show them here without closing modal 
    //laravel give you error in json array form . foreach and append them on ul tag .  
    //$error = []; $.each(errors , function(val){$error[] = "<li>"+val+"</li>";});  $('ulid or class').html(error); 
    //empty html of this ulid or class if there is no error 
    // $('#squarespaceModal').modal('hide');    

 }else{
   //show error  
   $('ulid or class').html('<li>This is error</li>');
  }
```

})

That is the basic idea , how you can achieve your goal .

Comment: Okay now the form wont close wich is what I need. But how to display errors ?

Comment: Ok check my answer again now